# Static Analysis tools at method/function level?

Tags: java, static-analysis

Recently I got into using static analysis tools like sonarqube and Teamscale.

However, they only show metrics at Project/Package/Class level. I am particularly interested in assessing the quality of Java methods, but the only tool I found that returns results at a method level was Sourcemeter and the respective plugin for Sonarqube.

Are there any other static analysis tools out there that provide metrics at a method level?

Comment: Any indications of budget, OS, etc?

Comment: @SteveBarnes This is for a research project, therefore I don't have to stick to a certain OS or am limited to a budget etc.

Comment: It might be worth editing your question to specify "Free or Low Cost" as some of the tools that I am aware of cost many thousands.

Answer (score 1):

Many linters are available, and usually report at the method/function level.

A couple that are worth looking at for Java are:

- Lint4j from [jutils](http://www.jutils.com/)
- [Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/)
- [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/)
- [FindBugs](https://github.com/findbugsproject/findbugs)

It might even be worth taking a look at [squale](http://www.squale.org/)!

There is even a linter built into the Oracle Javac compiler (enabled with the -Xlint flags)

Answer (score 0):

[JArchitect](https://www.jarchitect.com) tool gives you many metrics at a method level including Architecture/Design/Implementation metrics. And by using its code query language you can easily query exactly what you want as metrics, and also calculate your own ones based on the existing metrics.

> ```
> // <Name>Avoid methods too big, too complex</Name>
> warnif count > 0 from m in JustMyCode.Methods where 
>     (m.NbLinesOfCode > 35 ||
>    m.CyclomaticComplexity > 20)
>
>   let complexityScore = m.NbLinesOfCode/2 + m.CyclomaticComplexity 
>
>   orderby complexityScore descending,
>           m.CyclomaticComplexity descending
> select new { 
>    m, 
>    m.NbLinesOfCode,
>    m.CyclomaticComplexity, 
>    complexityScore,
>
>    Debt = complexityScore.Linear(30, 40,    400, 8*60).ToMinutes().ToDebt(),
>
>    // The annual interest varies linearly from interest for severity minor 
>    // to interest for severity major
>    AnnualInterest = complexityScore .Linear(30,     Severity.Medium.AnnualInterestThreshold().Value.TotalMinutes, 
>                                             200, 2*(Severity.High.AnnualInterestThreshold().Value.TotalMinutes)).ToMinutes().ToAnnualInterest()
>
> }
> ```